# Reusing Complex Object Instances in PHP

Tags: php

Is there a reasonable way to ensure that you aren't unnecessarily re-instantiating expensive object instances in PHP?

I have an application that deal with US States.  Each state is an instance of the `USState` class.  I'd like to ensure that the application only ever has one instance of each state object, although they are used in many places throughout the application.

I looked into the singleton pattern, but that seems to be used for times when a class only has a single instance - here there are 50 instances, but no more.

I guess I could put them in the global scope and always refer to them that way (`global $california`), but that seems wrong.

Comment: Maybe a Registry or Object Pool.

Answer (score 1):

I would use [Service Locator Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_locator_pattern) or Dependency Injection, which is provided by your framework. Usually I go with Zend Framework, but not knowing your circumstances, I assume you have no framework at all. In this case I would suggest very simple Dependency Injection Container, but that would add a dependency on DIC itself. [Pimple](http://pimple.sensiolabs.org/) is one of them.

Comment: It's a WordPress site with this state stuff grafted on (the states are not custom post types and use a different database table that isn't accessible from the CMS).  Adding dependencies is not an issue, it didn't seem like Pimple was meant for cases like this.  I'll give it a closer look -- thanks!